# How to ENABLE Open File security warning on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, security, powershell

I am a new user from `Windows 7` and I found there a nice features (`Open File - Security Warning` Message) is missing on my `Windows 10 version 1803`.

Note: I want to **ENABLE** it not *disable* it.

I have tried to run `inetcpl.cpl` and **reset** to *default*, or select `Prompt (recommend)` under **Launching applications and unsafe files**.

And also make sure the `Local Group Policy Editor` > `Attachment Manager` > `Do not preserve zone information in file attachments` is on `Not configured` state.

Want to show this:
[Open File - Security Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SELcQ.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Several solutions on how to enable it, may may lead you to how to enable it....https://windowsreport.com/open-file-security-warning/

Comment: @Moab the link you provided is `disable`. And I tried to do the opposite way it didn't work :(

Comment: Yep a typo on my part.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Yes, still having this problem. I don't know what do you mean by a screenshot. It just didn't show the `Open File - Security Warning` message when I open any files. Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I just want to have a default behavior of `Open File -Security Warning`, I have **never seen** the `Open File - Security Warning` **showing** on my win 10. I have done everything i could including add `HighRiskFileTypes` `.exe` to `HKEY_CU\.....\Policies\Associations`. Also, Site-to-Zone assignment list is not configured.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT pretty hopeless. It drives me crazy :(

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I don't think `UAC` is relevant here, even though I turned if on, it just did not showing.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I just tested 2 `Win10 (1903)` pc on my workplace, they have the same issue. It seen the `Open File - Security Warning` message only showing when I opened a file from intranet or copied a file from intranet to local pc then open it. Any ideas? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SELcQ.png)

Comment: the gpresult: https://pastebin.com/dZi0DPpC

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Are we on the same page? I want to see the security warning showing. The files from intranet showing warning is totally fine for me. The problem is other files like executable file downloaded from internet are not showing the `Open File - Security Warning`.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, Tried, didn't work. I think the the system cannot read the _wildcards_ syntax like that (http://evilgpo.blogspot.com/2016/03/internet-explorer-site-to-zone.html)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I am on a clean slate window 10 with only google chrome , so the problem should not be caused by the remnant reg. Also tested on two win 10 (all have the same problem), so I am wondering maybe the open file security warning are now only showing at intranet case? The win10 changed the showing behaviour? maybe it only affect newer version of `win10 (1803, 1902)`?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT tested on `C:\test` with a executable file after reboot, not working...

Comment: I'm out of ideas at the moment, you might cleanup the old comments though and perhaps add the detail with an [edit] to the question showing all the different things you have tried. If I think of something else I'll let you know but I've never had to reverse it as you are doing here. I'd be interesting to hear if you have an older version of Windows 10 than 1903? I know for a fact that this has popped up on 1803 for end users at one of the companies I support but I don't recall on 1903 personally. Is it happening on 1803 in your case too?